Is possible to remove a passenger from a wizzair flight?
I booked a flight with Wizz air for the whole family.
One member cannot travel, is possible to remove it from the booking?
Do I get a refund/credit?
How to do it?
I already tried on the app without success.

On some airlines, this can be done, but only by calling customer service. I don't know about Wizz though.

In my experience with WizzAir, you can probably do it by calling them, but the amount they charge for calling will eat up any refund.

You can call them and ask to "split the reservation". Than you can manage (and cancel) the reservations individually.

@Kyralessa That sounds like the system works ... for WizzAir.

If you can’t cancel via the app for some reason, you need to contact the Wizz Air call centre. To get a refund you first have to pay the cancellation fee:

€60-€80 up to 14 days before departure date
€80-€100 within 14 days of departure.


I would assume if the cost of the ticket is less than the fee you just forfeit it?

"To get a refund you first have to pay the cancellation fee". On the [money.se] site we always say "if you have to pay money before you get your money it's 100% a scam".

@DJClayworth Indeed, however it’s a scam the passenger signs up to when they book :-)
